# I have done self join in php but it gives wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the `DB` Structure

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | cat_title |  parent-cat_id | status            |  
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Main      |  null          | enabled           |
| 2  | Child     |  1             | enabled           |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I have written this query for Self Joining

```
SELECT a.id as ID, a.cat_title as Title, s.cat_title as parent_category
FROM store_categories a
LEFT JOIN store_categories s ON s.parent_cat_id =a.id
```

But it gives me wrong result like that. because `Main` didn't have a `parent_category` and `Child` have a `parent_category` of `Main`. and in result, it shows `Main` has a `parent_category`  and `Child` has not.

```
-----------------------------
| ID | Title |  parent-cat_id|  
-----------------------------
| 1  | Main      |  Child    |
| 2  | Child     |  null     |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried to amend your ON clause to be `a.parent_cat_id =s.id`

Comment: @NigelRen it works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you are linking the two versions of the table is the wrong way round, you just need to change the ON clause...

```
SELECT a.id as ID, a.cat_title as Title, s.cat_title as parent_category 
    FROM store_categories a 
    LEFT JOIN store_categories s 
       ON a.parent_cat_id =s.id
```